# Gathering information from Google+ Sign in with C#/ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth, google-plus, google-oauth

Ok, I've been through a ton of documentation, "quick guides", and samples from Google, but nothing is making much sense to me, so I apologise in advance if I don't make much sense. I'm fairly new to ASP and MVC. I really don't know what my next step is.

I have a very simple task, I want to log into my ASP.NET MVC 4 application with Google+, and then access user information (Name, Address, Gender) using C#, in my HomeController.cs class.

I am using the default ASP.NET template project (Razor), and successfully added my client ID and secret to Startup.Auth.cs, and I can log in with my Google+ account, and I have the proper scopes.

Startup.Auth.cs:

```
app.UseGooglePlusAuthentication(
                clientId: "CLIENT-ID",
                clientSecret: "CLIENT-SECRET");
```

Now from here is where I'm stumped.

The example at the bottom of this page is exactly what I want to do, except it does not provide a C#/ASP example.

**My questions are:**
How can I access account information from my HomeController once I've successfully logged in with Google+?

What is my next step? I would greatly appreciate it if someone could direct me in the right direction.

Many thanks, this was a last resort.

Comment: check this link if it can help you http://www.strathweb.com/2012/08/adding-openid-authentication-to-your-asp-net-mvc-4-application/

Comment: Thanks, that guide uses OpenID, but I'll see what I can do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following should set you on the right lines:

```
var externalIdentity = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetExternalIdentityAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
var extEmailClaim = externalIdentity.Result.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email);
var extEmail = emailClaim.Value;
```

You should be able to follow the above pattern to access other pieces of data relating to your user by adjusting the **ClaimTypes** value within the lambda expression.

Please see the following link for other ClaimTypes values: [ClaimTypes Class - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimtypes(v=vs.110).aspx)